# Jquery functions continue to apply even the CSS is changed. How do I stop this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brvsirrobin/6g4nzjtv/10/) first.

I have `nameCards` which expand and contract when clicked by adding/removing classes. Additionally, they move to different sections in the page when buttons are clicked (again by adding/removing classes). The problem: Despite them no longer having the classes needed to trigger the functions, the function still applies to them.

In the code, they move from `.unmatched` to `.matched`, so the function selector `$('.matched.nameCard')` should no longer work, but it does, as shown by the fact that the alert from the `.click()` still shows after it got moved.

I've tried `event.stopProgation()` basically everywhere in the functions, tried using a local variable instead of the global variable `currentCard`, and have double checked that the classes are changing by inspecting using `.html`. By my reasoning, the second they change from `.unmatched` to `.matched` the original function should stop working. Can anybody help me figure out why it's not?

Final note, the formatting got screwed up a little in the switch to fiddle, please forgive the funkyness. I tried to get rid of as much extra stuff as possible.

Edit: Changed from `#matched` in my question to `.matched`

Full code:
HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
  <h2>Unmatched:</h2>
  <div class="container-fluid matchBoxes" id="unmatched">
    <div class="namesAndModals">
      <div class="nameCard preClick unmatched" id="unmatchedFunctionalityShell">
        <h2 class="memberName"></h2>
            <div class="nameCardContents">
          <button type="button" class="btn checkmark" id="yesBtn" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pairModal">
        <div class="checkmark_circle"></div>
        <div class="checkmark_stem"></div>
        <div class="checkmark_kick"></div>
      </button>

      <input type="text" placeholder="PNM ID#" class="IDnum ansField" autofocus/>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" class="lastName ansField" id="lastName"/>
                <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="firstName ansField" id="firstName"/>
            </div>
        </div>

      <div class="nameCard preClick unmatched">
          <h2 class="memberName">Jane Doe</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="nameCard preClick unmatched">
          <h2 class="memberName">Jane Doe</h2>
        </div>


  <!-- Pairing Modal -->
  <div id="pairModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Ready to Pair?</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p id="pairDialog"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="pairButton" data-dismiss="modal">Pair</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="dismissButton" data-dismiss="modal">Never Mind</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>    
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<h2>Matched:</h2>
  <div class="container-fluid matchBoxes" id="matched">
    <div class="nameCard preClick matched">
      <h2 class="memberName">Jane Doe</h2>
        <div class="matchedNameCardContents">
          <p class="pnmName">Jaime Doe</p>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    font-family: 'Gill Sans MT', 'Microsoft YaHai UI', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 200;
}

#unmatched {
  width: auto;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgba(211, 211, 211, .55);
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  min-width: 270px;
}

#matched {
  width: 110%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(211, 211, 211, .55);
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  min-width: 270px;
}

.nameCard {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: rgba(255,100,171,.5);
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: block;
  margin: 2px 1px;
  overflow:auto;
}

.nameCard.preClick {
  height: 30px;
}
.nameCard .nameCardContents {
  display:none;
}

.nameCard h2 {
  display:inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 5px 0 3px 10px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 75%;
  float:left;
}

.nameCard .IDnum {
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 5px 2px 3px 10px;
  padding: 3px 0px 3px 2px;
  width: 25%;
}

.nameCard .lastName {
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 5px 2px 3px 2px;
  padding: 3px 0px 3px 2px;
  width: 30%;
}

.nameCard .firstName {
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 5px 2px 3px 2px;
  padding: 3px 0px 3px 2px;
  width: 30%;
}

#unmatchedFunctionalityShell {
    display:none;
}
.checkmark {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:auto;
    margin-right:2px;
    padding-right:0px;
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.checkmark_circle {
    position: absolute;
    width:22px;
    height:22px;
    background-color: rgba(46,195,1,.8);
    border-radius:11px;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}

.checkmark_stem {
    position: absolute;
    width:3px;
    height:9px;
    background-color:#fff;
    left:11px;
    top:6px;
}

.checkmark_kick {
    position: absolute;
    width:3px;
    height:3px;
    background-color:#fff;
    left:8px;
    top:12px;
}
#yesBtn{
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: rgba(46,195,1,0);
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    border-radius:11px;
}

/* Matched Members */

.matched.nameCard {
  background-color: rgba(50, 205, 50, .5);
}

.matched p {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.matched .btn {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgba(255,37,37,.7);   
    padding: 4px;
    float:right;
}

/*I had to use important here to get rid of the nameCardContents. Try and remove it later */
#matched .nameCardContents {
  display:none !important;
}

#matched .preClick .matchedNameCardContents {
    display:none;
}
```

Javascript

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.unmatched.nameCard').hover(function() {
    var currentCard = $(this);
      var memberName = $(this).children(".memberName").text();

      currentCard.off('click').on("click", function(event) {
        //  alert("hello");
        //switches between "active" and "inactive (preClick)" card
        $("#unmatched .nameCard").addClass('nameCard preClick');
          currentCard.toggleClass('nameCard');
        currentCard.toggleClass('nameCard preClick');

        var cardContents = $('.nameCardContents');
        cardContents.appendTo(currentCard);


        if (currentCard.is(".nameCard.preClick") ) {
          cardContents.hide();
          alert("this shouldn't happen after being moved to #matched");
        } else {
          cardContents.show();
        alert("this shouldn't happen after being moved to #matched");
        }
      });


      //stops card from closing if you click on buttons/input and carries out button events
      currentCard.off('click', ".btn").on("click", ".btn", function(event) {
      var pnmLastName = $("#lastName").val();
        var pnmFirstName = $('#firstName').val();
          $("#pairDialog").text("Are you sure you want to pair " + memberName + " with " + pnmFirstName + "  " + pnmLastName + "?");
      });

    currentCard.off('click', ".ansField").on("click", ".ansField", function(event) {
          event.stopPropagation();
      });

      //Unmatched to Matched
    $('#pairModal #pairButton').off('click').on("click", function(event) {
          var pnmLastName = $("#lastName").val();
        var pnmFirstName = $('#firstName').val();
          currentCard.removeClass('unmatched');
          currentCard.addClass('matched');
          currentCard.children(".nameCardContents").hide();
          currentCard.append("<div class='matchedNameCardContents'><p class='pnmName'>" + pnmFirstName + " " + pnmLastName + "</p><button type='button' class='btn btn-default'  data-toggle='modal' data-target='#unpairModal'>Unpair</button></div>");
          currentCard.addClass('preClick');
          currentCard.prependTo("#matched");
          $("#lastName").val("");
          $("#firstName").val("");
      });

      //Move from Unmatched to Unavailible
      //Remove for one party
      $('#discardModal #onePartyButton').off('click').on("click", function(event) {
          currentCard.removeClass('unmatched');
          currentCard.addClass('unavailable');
          currentCard.prependTo("#unavailable");
          var newDiv = $("<div><p>Removed for one party</p></div>")
          newDiv.appendTo(currentCard);
      });

    //Remove for one round
      $('#discardModal #oneRoundButton').off('click').on("click", function(event) {
          currentCard.removeClass('unmatched');
          currentCard.addClass('unavailable');
          currentCard.prependTo("#unavailable");
          var newDiv = $("<div><p>Removed for one round</p></div>")
          newDiv.appendTo(currentCard);
      });
      //Remove for all recruitment
      $('#discardModal #allRecruitmentButton').off('click').on("click", function(event) {
          currentCard.removeClass('unmatched');
          currentCard.addClass('unavailable');
          currentCard.prependTo("#unavailable");
          var newDiv = $("<div><p>Removed from recruitment</p></div>")
          newDiv.appendTo(currentCard);
      });
    });
    });

    //Matched Name cards

    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.matched.nameCard').off().hover(function() {     
    var currentCard = $(this); 
      var memberName = $(this).children(".memberName").text();
      var pnmName = $(this).children(".pnmName").text();

      currentCard.on("click", function(event) {
      //switches between "active" and "inactive (preClick)" card
          //$("#matched .nameCard").addClass('nameCard preClick');
      currentCard.toggleClass('nameCard');
        currentCard.toggleClass('nameCard preClick');

        var cardContents = $('.matchedNameCardContents');   

        if (currentCard.is(".nameCard.preClick") ) {
          cardContents.hide();
        } else {
          cardContents.show();
        }  
      });


      //stops card from closing if you click on buttons/input and carries out button events
      currentCard.on("click", ".btn", function(event) {
          $("#unpairButton").text("Are you sure you want to unpair " + memberName + " and " + pnmName + "?");
      });

    currentCard.on("click", ".ansField", function(event) {
          event.stopPropagation();
      });

      //.unbind() is the best thing to happen to me

      //Unmatched to Matched
    $('#pairModal #pairButton').unbind('click').on("click", function(event) {
          var pnmLastName = $("#lastName").val();
        var pnmFirstName = $('#firstName').val();
          currentCard.removeClass('unmatched');
          currentCard.addClass('matched');
          currentCard.children(".nameCardContents").hide();
          var addPNM = $("<div class='matchedNameCardContents'><p class='pnmName'>" + pnmFirstName + " " + pnmLastName + "</p><button type='button' class='btn btn-default'  data-toggle='modal' data-target='#unpairModal'>Unpair</button></div>");
          currentCard.append("<div><p class='pnmName'>" + pnmFirstName + " " + pnmLastName + "</p><button type='button' class='btn btn-default'  data-toggle='modal' data-target='#unpairModal'>Unpair</button></div>");
          currentCard.prependTo("#matched");
      });
    });
    });
```

Comment: Are you referencing `#matched` or `.matched`?

Comment: Your understanding on the event binding is wrong. Once you choose a element and add a click event it sticks on to the element unless you explicitly remove it using `off` or the element is removed from DOM. Changing classes, content, position of the element will have no effect on the injected event. It just sticks on to it.

Comment: What would be a quick fix would be to use `event delegation`. This means you write a click event to either `document` or `body` or the parent wrapper. And when ever there is a click on this element you check was it on the element with specific selector. Like `$(document).on('click','.matched.nameCards',function(){....`

Comment: On the `#matched` vs `.matched`, I edited the question for clarity. I should have been using `.matched` because that's the jquery selector.

Comment: So if I understand you Rajshekar, instead of using `$(document).ready(function() { $('.unmatched.nameCard').on().....`, I should just be using what you suggested? How would I handle the nested clicks inside of the `.hover()` function that I currently have?

Comment: I am not 100% sure of what I am about to say. It is just a suggestion. Before adding class, remove the class unwanted class first.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I looked into event delegation based on the comments and changed everything to take that into account. Here's a preview of what my new functions look like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#unmatched').off().on("mouseover", ".unmatched.nameCard", function() {
      var currentCard = $(this);
      var memberName = $(this).children(".memberName").text();

      currentCard.off('click').on("click", function() {
        //switches between "active" and "inactive (preClick)" card
        $("#unmatched .nameCard").addClass('nameCard preClick');
        currentCard.toggleClass('nameCard');
        currentCard.toggleClass('nameCard preClick');

        var cardContents = $('.nameCardContents');
        cardContents.appendTo(currentCard);


        if (currentCard.is(".nameCard.preClick") ) {
          cardContents.hide();
        } else {
          cardContents.show();
        }
      });


      //stops card from closing if you click on buttons/input and carries out button events
      currentCard.off('click', ".btn").on("click", ".btn", function(event) {
        var pnmLastName = $("#lastName").val();
        var pnmFirstName = $('#firstName').val();
        $("#pairDialog").text("Are you sure you want to pair " + memberName + " with " + pnmFirstName + "  " + pnmLastName + "?");
        $("#removeMember").text("How long do you want to remove " + memberName + " from recruitment?");
      });
    });
  });
```